# Django matching a url with paramater to start

Tags: django

I've got a site I'm working on where I need to match a parameter at the start
of the url: 
`test.com/the-data-slug`

What is odd is I can't figure out why the following code dosen't work.
It dosen't match at all.

```
path('<slug:data-slug>/', DataLandingView.as_view(), name="data_landing")
```

I did get the following to work, but I know path is prefered over re_path.

```
re_path(r'^(?P<data-slug>\w+)/$', DataLandingView.as_view(), name="data_landing")
```

I'm really curious what I'm doing wrong with the path call, or is this just something path can't do?

**Update:**
Requested from commenters.
From urls.py these are the only url patterns in use.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Special Project level routing. Specifically routes to handle login/logout admin
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    # We are handling all convention level routing here as it makes more
    # sence here as a master control router than in the individual projects

    # Global Stuff for buisness
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),    

    # If we don't recoginze from the above we step down to the next layer
    path('<slug:data-slug>', CLandingView.as_view(), name="c_landing")
]
```

Going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc-2020
and http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc-2020/
returns a 'Page Not Found' Exception

But if I use the following route with re_path. It works.

```
re_path(r'^(?P<c_name>[-\w]+)/$', CLandingView.as_view(), name="c_landing")
```

Comment: does it work with ```test.com/the-data-slug/``` with slash at the end?

Comment: could you show all the url patterns? It may be that some url pattern, like "/" is matching first. If you have a "/" pattern, move it below the "/<slug>/ one

Comment: @AndreyNelubin nope / dosen't have a diffrence.

Comment: @NikitaTonkoskur updated question with url patterns.

Comment: @huntsfromshadow try moving your `<slug>` pattern so it will appear before the `path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),`
Another issue why you may have `404` errors is that model that is assigned to `CLandingView` view, doesn't have objects with requested slugs.

Comment: @NikitaTonkoskur moving it ahead of the '' path didn't help. Don't get your comment about 'requested slugs', but tried to move it to path('<str:data-slug>' to see if it would just take a string, still befmore the '', HomePageView path, and it still didn't work.